# PHP Print and Echo HTML

Tags: php, html, printing, echo, nowdoc

very simple question. Lol i am embarassed to ask this cause i am usually very good with php but what are the ways to display html inside of php? for example:

```
<? if($flag): ?>
  <div>This will show is $flag is true </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

OR

```
<?
  if($flag)
    echo '<div>This will show is $flag is true </div>';
?>
```

I know that there are at least 2 other ways i just cannot remember them atm...
Help is def. appreciated in advance!! =D

Comment: You should use single quotes (`'`) with echo. Double quotes (`"`) are interpreted differently and PHP is going to replace `$flag` with `$flag`s value. Use single quotes if you want the same behaviour as in your first example.

Comment: thanks elusive made the edits

Comment: [Everything you ever wanted to know about strings but were afraid to ask](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php "PHP Manual on Strings")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) could be used:

```
if($flag)
{
    echo <<<HTML
        <div>This will show if \$flag is true </div>
HTML;

}
```

If you don't want variable interpolation, you have to escape possible varnames as I have above. Alternatively, you can use a [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) with PHP 5.3 onwards:

```
if($flag)
{
    echo <<<'HTML'
        <div>This will show if $flag is true </div>
HTML;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 0):

PHP also has a [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax that works like [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), but similar to single quoted strings, these doc blocks do not get parsed.