# How can I display something to a user with php in my web app?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I want to be able to show an output to the user when he tries to log in or sign up and he isn't able to. Ideally I want to be able to call a `JavaScript` function from a file or at least call `prompt()` or something like that. The code is the following:

```
<?php
include("../php/functions.php");
include("../php/connect.php");

do{
    if(isset($_POST['submit-btn'])) {
        $loggedIn = authenticate($conn, $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
        if($loggedIn === null) {
            /**TODO: Do something when the database couldn't be reached */
            break;
        }

        if(!$loggedIn) {
            /***TODO: Do something when the password is incorrect*/
            break;
        }
        if($loggedIn)
            header("Location: ../html/homepage.html");
    }
}while(false)

?>
```

I get the data from `$_POST['*value*']` after the user has submited it and I don't know how to show a, somewhat, presentable error message to he user.

Comment: You can [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) any text message or HTML elements and also `<script>` elements with javascript inside. No need for the `do ... while`

Comment: I know but I don't  I will do this as a last resort

Comment: Do what as a last resort? "_I want to be able to show an output to the user_" sounds like you want to ... output something to the user, that's (usually) done by `echo`ing something

Comment: I have seen outputs like that in other posts but they say that they don't call the functions that you write in the echo.

Comment: I' sorry but I don't quite understand that last comment. You can also step out of PHP using `?>` and add regular HTML code if you don't want to use `echo` or functions. Remember to step in using `<?php` again when you want to do PHP stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Print and Echo HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033051/php-print-and-echo-html)

Answer (score 1):

Showing an output to the user on an unsuccessful login should be as simple changing your code from this:

```
if(!$loggedIn) {
    /***TODO: Do something when the password is incorrect*/
    break;
}
```

to this:

```
if(!$loggedIn) {
    echo "<p>Login unsuccessful!</p>";
    break;
}
```

If you want to call a JavaScript function you also can do it with the same approach:

```
if(!$loggedIn) {
    echo "<script>function warning() { alert('Wrong password!'); } warning();</script>";
    break;
}
```